# wind load (force exerted) on canopy area

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I am working in agriculture vine yards that has relatively stronger wind pressure to my vine crops.

- how can i calculate the load of the perpendicular or at some angle prevailing wind to the closed canopy(branches) of the vine crop? And
- how can i relate the result of the calculation with the material *(supporting pole and tension wire)* that can secure my vine from collapse?

Comment: Drag equation may help somewhat. Force = 0.5 x air_density x drag_coefficient x Area x air velocity squared. In SI units that reduces in simple cases to F_Newtons = 0.6 x Area_m^2 x Velocity_m/s at sea level. Reduces logarithmically with altitude and has halved by ~= 4000 metres.

Comment: This is very difficult to solve analytically, as many things will affect the answer (wind speed and gusts, density and type of foliage, elasticity of the supporting poles and tension wires, etc. etc. etc.). Your most reliably answer would probably be found through experience and by consulting others who have solved this through their own experience.